# How can I compare two arrays with different sizes but with some floats that are approximate?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, compare, precision

How can I compare two arrays with different sizes but with some floats that are approximate? For example:

```
# I have two arrays
a = np.array( [-2.83, -2.54, ..., 0.05, ..., 2.54, 2.83] )
b = np.array( [-3.0, -2.9, -2.8, ..., -0.1, 0.0, 0.1, ..., 2.9, 3.0] )
# wherein len( b ) > len( a )
```

What I need is the index where (considering those two values from both lists)

```
math.isclose( -2.54, -2.5, rel_tol=1e-1) == True
```

The answer that I need is something like

```
list_of_index_of_b = [1, 5, ..., -2]
```

Here `list_of_index_of_b` is a list with the "coordinates" where that specific element of `b` is approximate to some element of `a`. Not all ellements of `a` have an approximate in `b`. Also:
`len(list_of_index_of_b) == len(a)`

Comment: len(list_of_index_of_b) == len(a) ?

Comment: If `a` and `b` are not too large a simple method would be `np.where(np.isclose(*np.ix_(a, b), rtol=1e-1))`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use broadcasting. This creates an array of the pairwise differences between every element in `a` and `b` which you can then check against the specified tolerance.

```
a - b[:,None]
```

We can then scale the difference by the size of the `b` vectors:

```
(1/np.abs(b)[:,None])*np.abs(a - b[:,None])
```

We can threshold to get the pairs of `a` and `b` which are close

```
mask2d = (1/np.abs(b)[:,None])*np.abs(a - b[:,None]) < rtol
```

Finally, we can return a boolean array which is 1 in the indices where `b` has an entry near to some entry of `a`, and 0 otherwise:

```
mask = np.any(mask2d,axis=1)
```

Of course this is computationally inefficient from a complexity standpoint since you construct an array of size `|a|*|b|` and compare every pairwise distance against the tolerance, even if once of the differences is already small enough. That said, if one of `|a|` or `|b|` is relatively small, then then this approach can be quite fast since it is pure numpy and requires no loops.

Complete example:

```
a = np.array([1,5,6,7])
b = np.array([1.1,2,3,4.8,4.9,5,8])

rtol = 0.15

mask2d = (1/np.abs(b)[:,None])*np.abs(a - b[:,None]) < rtol
mask = np.any(mask2d,axis=1)
```

Comment: This answer produces a broadcasting error:
"ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,) (7,4) "

Comment: updated, needed to broadcast the product with 1/abs(b) as well